# How do I `hostnamectl set-icon-name` via Ansible?

Tags: ansible, hostname, ansible-facts, almalinux

Red Hat has a command called `hostnamectl set-icon-name`. Is it correct to configure this using Ansible?

The usual command

```yaml
ansible.builtin.shell: "hostnamectl set-icon-name {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

is possible, of course, but with each pass the Ansible thinks that it is changing this parameter, which is not good.

Comment: See [defining "changed"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed)

Comment: Are you sure that the icon name should be equal to the hostname from inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **"*Red Hat has a command called `hostnamectl` ...*"**

That's right. It is usually used in order to [Changing a hostname](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/assembly_changing-a-hostname_configuring-and-managing-networking#proc_changing-a-hostname-using-hostnamectl_assembly_changing-a-hostname). See also [`hostnamectl` — Control the system hostname](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/hostnamectl.html).

Plase take note about [What is different between `Static hostname` and `Icon name` and `Pretty hostname` in RHEL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/357925/266568) and the fact that `hostname != icon-name`.

> *`icon-name [NAME]`*
>
> *If no argument is given, print the icon name of the system. If an optional argument `NAME` is provided then the command changes the icon name to `NAME`. The icon name is used by some graphical applications to visualize this host. The icon name should follow the [Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html#names).*

So, for a server the `Icon name` should probably set to `computer`, `computer-vm` or `computer-server` if not already

```bash
~/test$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: test.example.com
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 1234567890abcdefghijkl1234567890
           Boot ID: 1234567890abcdefghijkl1234567890
    Virtualization: microsoft
  Operating System: RHEL
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.105.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

~/test$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: test.example.com
         Icon name: computer-server
           Chassis: server
        Machine ID: 1234567890abcdefghijkl1234567890
           Boot ID: 1234567890abcdefghijkl1234567890
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9 (Ootpa)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

or according the mentioned [naming convention](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html#context) to

> *Icons for hardware that is contained within or connected to the computing device. Naming for extended devices in this group, is of the form `<primary function>-<manufacturer>-<model>`. This allows ease of fallback to the primary function device name, or ones more targeted for a specific series of models from a manufacturer.*

Since the Ansible [`hostname` module – Manage hostname](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/hostname_module.html) is for setting the hostname only

> *Set system’s hostname. Supports most OSs/Distributions including those using `systemd`.*

one is left with a [`command` module – Execute commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html) and [Defining "changed"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed) since the [`hostname` Exit status](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/hostnamectl.html#Exit%20status) will be just be

> *On success, 0 is returned, a non-zero failure code otherwise.*

and in order to gain [Idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency). This is also due to the fact that [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) do not gather the `Icon name` and if no additional [Custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts) are implemented.

> ***Is it correct to configure this using Ansible? The usual command
> `ansible.builtin.shell: "hostnamectl set-icon-name {{ inventory_hostname }}` is possible, of course, but with each pass the Ansible thinks that it is changing this parameter, which is not good.***

Finally, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    ICON_NAME: computer-vm

  tasks:

  - name: Gather Facts via 'hostnamectl' without leading white-space
    shell: hostnamectl | sed "s/^[ \t]*//"
    register: HOSTNAMECTL
    # Since it is reporting task which should run in any case, set
    check_mode: false
    changed_when: false

  - name: Show Facts to get familiar with the data structure
    debug:
      msg: "{{ (HOSTNAMECTL.stdout | from_yaml) }}"

  - name: Set 'Icon name' via 'hostnamectl' idempotent
    command: hostnamectl set-icon-name {{ ICON_NAME }}
    when: (HOSTNAMECTL.stdout | from_yaml)['Icon name'] != ICON_NAME
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Gather Facts via 'hostnamectl' without leading white-spaces] *********************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show Facts to get familiar with the data structure] ******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    Architecture: x86-64
    Boot ID: 1234567890abcdefghijkl1234567890
    CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server
    Chassis: vm
    Icon name: computer-vm
    Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.105.1.el7.x86_64
    Machine ID: 1234567890abcdefghijkl1234567890
    Operating System: RHEL
    Static hostname: test.example.com
    Virtualization: microsoft

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1
```

If a `skipped` tasks is not the desired behavior one could change the condition to

```yaml
  - name: Set 'Icon name' via 'hostnamectl' idempotent
    command: hostnamectl set-icon-name {{ ICON_NAME }}
    changed_when: (HOSTNAMECTL.stdout | from_yaml)['Icon name'] != ICON_NAME
```